# Is there a file size limit when using the O365 Unified API Group Files upload method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, office365, office365api

As title, is there a limit on file size when using this method?: https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/HowTo/groups-rest-operations#UpdateGroupFile

I can upload files up to ~4MB in size, but larger than this and I get an unhelpful HTTP Error 500 returned from the API?

Sounds suspiciously like the [4MB default limit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms827741.aspx) within .NET.

I've looked around the documentation, but I can't find any reference to there being a limit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we have a small limit today. Soon we will be adding support for chunked upload functions that will enable larger file upload.

Comment: Updates on when this will be available?